# .htaccess unable to pass pretty url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulty getting the .htaccess to rewrite my urls correctly.
I have an api file which is expecting parameters of `function`, `user`, `id`, `action`, `profileid`.

```
RewriteRule   ^phonebook/user/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$  /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2;action=$3;profileid=$4
RewriteRule   ^phonebook/user/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$       /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2;action=$3
RewriteRule   ^phonebook/user/(.+)/(.+)$            /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2
RewriteRule   ^phonebook/user(.+)$                  /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1
RewriteRule   ^phonebook/(.+)                       /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;id=$1
RewriteRule   ^phonebook(.*)                        /api.fcgi?function=phonebook$1
```

When i call `/phonebook/user/12345/1` it is rewritten as
`function=phonebook;user=12345;id=1`. This is correct and would have been rewritten on the 3rd rule from the top.

However when i call `/phonebook/user/12345/1/destination` it is written as 
`function=phonebook;user=12345;id=1/destination` where as i expected, `function=phonebook;user=12345;id=1;action=destination`

Likewise, `/phonebook/user/12345/1/destination/1` is rewritten as
`function=phonebook;user=12345;id=1/destination/1` when it should be `function=phonebook;user=12345;id=1;action=destination;profileid=1`

As the bottom 4 lines have been rewriting true, i'm bit confused as to why the top two rules aren't being picked up. Any help would be grateful as this one has caused a few question marks

Comment: Have you tried adding the `[L]` flag after each rule? That should prevent any further rules processing if there are matches

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.+` as that is too greedy. Use `[^/]+` instead:

```
RewriteRule ^phonebook/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2;action=$3;profileid=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phonebook/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2;action=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phonebook/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1;id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phonebook/user([^/]+)$ /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phonebook/([^/]+) /api.fcgi?function=phonebook;id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phonebook(.*) /api.fcgi?function=phonebook$1
```